# Empathy messages don't show up in message indicator

Tags: 11.10, indicator, empathy, messaging-menu

Since upgrading to 11.10, sometimes Empathy messages don't show up in the message indicator applet. Is this a known regression or a "feature?"

I think the problem occurs when the chat window is already open, the indicator applet isn't notified (doesn't turn blue or have an event in the queue). Wasn't this something fixed in the 10.10 -> 11.04 update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already [a filed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/842428). See the discussion there for more info.